# Main Title is not Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my main title is not changing size to fit the device, it just stays the same size instead of being responsive. [here is a picture of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkN40.jpg)

HTML:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px)
.middle-content .intro-text .name {
  font-size: 4.75em;
}

.middle-content  .intro-text .name {
  display: block;
  font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Intro Section -->
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="middle-content col-lg-12">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <h1 class="name">nlythdsgnr</h1>
          <span class="skills">graphic designer</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1)change `color: white;` to `color: #000;` for better result.
>
> 2)you miss `{}` in @media code.
>
> 3) replace css Codes like this :

```
.middle-content  .intro-text .name {
    display: block;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 7em;
    color: #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width:740px) {
.middle-content .intro-text .name {
    font-size: 4.75em;
 }
}
```

> 4)Other Change.

This is [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4fsuzmqb/2/)

Comment: White should be `#fff`, pretty hard to see on the white background though ;)

Comment: background is white and color is white,how can you see result @TheF?

Comment: Hi, this works but the title starts small then when the device is resised, the title gets bigger. how do i change this around? @ehsan

Comment: you can use `max-width:798px` or other values.

Comment: it is ok? or not?

Comment: @ehsan sorry i was away for a while. thank you this helped!